# Is the following a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space of all polynomials of degree at most 3, is the following a linear subspace ?

$a+bt+ct^{2}+dt^{3}$ which have a root of 3.

I am unsure of how to show whether or not this is a vector space. I know in order to prove something is a linear vector space we need to show that vector addition and scalar multiplication hold.

Comment: What means "have a root of $3$" ? Does it mean "$3$ is a root of $a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ ?

Comment: To be very strict, a polynomial, such as $a+ bt+ ct^2+ dt^3$ does **not** have "roots".  An **equation** has roots.  The roots to the equation $a+ bt+ ct^2+ dt^3= 0$ are the "zeros" of the polynomial $a+ bt+ ct^2+ dt^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that if $f(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ has a root of $3$, then $f(t)$ is divisible by $t-3$, so $f(t)=(t-3)(dt^2+(c+3d)t-\frac{a}{3})$.

Comment: This is actually more than is needed here.

Comment: @vadim123 If you want to prove $f(t)+g(t)$ also has a root of three, you can factor the $t-3$ out of the sum using the formula above and then using the fact that $t-3$ is a factor of $f(t)+g(t)$, conclude that $3$ is a root of $f(t)+g(t)$. This method works, although yours works as well.

Answer (score 4):

Step 0: Prove that there is some polynomial in $V$ that has a root of 3.  Here's one: $p(x)=x-3$.  Done!

Step 1: If $p(x)\in V$ has a root of 3, and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (or whatever your ground field is if it's not $\mathbb{R}$), can you prove that $cp(x)$  has a root of 3?

Step 2: If $p(x),q(x)\in V$, and they both have roots of 3, can you prove that $p(x)+q(x)$ has a root of 3?

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation map $${\rm ev}_3:\quad V\to{\mathbb R},\qquad p\mapsto p(3)$$ is a linear functional on $V$, hence ${\rm ker}({\rm ev}_3)$ is a subspace of $V$.